# singular nouns after a plural possessive form

Tags: singular-vs-plural, possessives, plural-forms

This is perhaps a bit of a strange question, but it's bugging me no end.
I know that it is acceptable to use both a singular and a plural noun after a plural possessive, e.g. "..this influences people's lives/this influences people's life" are both considered correct as far as I know...
Now I have a sentence here which goes "... this influences students' mind" and it just doesn't sound right. Is that just me?

Answer (score 2):

It's acceptable to use a singular noun after a plural possessive when the noun refers to a singular thing that is shared between multiple people (or animals, etc.):

> We took **our watch** to the watchmaker. *(There's one watch which we share ownership of)*
>
> We took **our watches** to the watchmaker. *(Each of us has their own watch)*

So grammatically, there's nothing wrong with any of the sentences you've brought up.

The reason why *people's life* is more acceptable than *students' mind* is that it's acceptable to consider *life* in some contexts to be "shared" between people (for example, you can write a thesis about *the life of peasants in 15th century England*, treating *life* as a total of experiences of all the peasants, rather than focus on individual *lives* of them). On the other hand, we usually treat each person as having their own *mind*.

That said, when it comes to abstract concepts such as *life* or *mind* that line is rather  blurry. I personally wouldn't be very strongly opposed to *students' mind*.

Comment: Thank you very much for a very clear and concise answer to my question. Yes, I can see that there is bit of personal judgement involved here and what bugs me doesn't necessarily bug other people, but now I understand why.